# Java Path Finder NumericValueChecker

Tags: java, path-finding, jpf

I am trying to learn Java Path Finder (JPF). I downloaded the JPF and build it. Currently I have **jpf-core** folder which has example .java files together with their corresponding .jpf files. My goal is to create a new basic .java file and check whether a specific value in this file exceeds the max-bound I specified in the .jpf file.

**In the examples folder** there is .java file called NumericValueCheck.java which is exactly what I want, and it works as expected. (finds when the value exceeds the bound)

**NumericValueCheck.java**

```
public class NumericValueCheck {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    double someVariable;
    someVariable = 42;  
    someVariable = 60; 
  }
}
```

**NumericValueCheck.jpf**

```
target = NumericValueCheck

listener = .listener.NumericValueChecker

# NumericValueChecker configuration
range.vars = 1
range.1.var = NumericValueCheck.main(java.lang.String[]):someVariable
range.1.min = 0
range.1.max = 42
```

However, I created a new .java file and named it "**BasicCheck.java**". Here is the code inside it;

```
public class BasicCheck {
public static void main(String[] args){
    double result;
    result = 60;
    result = 110;
    }
}
```

Here are the properties in **BasicCheck.jpf**;

```
target = BasicCheck

listener = .listener.NumericValueChecker

# NumericValueChecker configuration
range.vars = 1
range.1.var = BasicCheck.main(java.lang.String[]):result
range.1.min = 0
range.1.max = 60
```

I compiled the BasicCheck.java using `javac BasicCheck.java` in a separate directory. Then I copy "BasicCheck.java" and "BasicCheck.jpf" to **examples** folder of jpf-core where NumericValueCheck.java and NumericValueCheck.jpf also in the same place. I also copy "BasicCheck.class" to `jpf-core/build/examples` directory where "NumericValueCheck.class" also in the same place.

However, when I run the command `java -jar build/RunJPF.jar src/examples/BasicCheck.jpf`, it can't find any error. The result is "no error detected". It should detect 110 which is bigger than the upper bound 60.

Why is it not working? Do I need to add something extra to my new BasicCheck.java or BasicCheck.jpf ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a long effort. The solution is simple.

Put **BasicCheck.java** and **BasicCheck.jpf** under the directory `jpf-core/src/examples`.

Do **NOT** compile to source using `javac`.  Open the terminal and `cd` to `jpf-core` directory. Then type the following command: `./gradlew buildJars`.

That's it. Now you can use the command `java -jar build/RunJPF.jar src/examples/BasicCheck.jpf` to run Java Path Finder.